# Which combinations of NAT requires TURN servers?

Tags: networking, nat, webrtc

I wanna test my Webrtc app, as part of this, I need to test the app with different NAT Types.

Here I'm not sure, in which combinations the TURN server is required for the below NAT Types:

- Full Cone
- Restricted Cone
- Port Restricted
- Symmetric

I went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424904/what-type-of-nat-combinations-requires-a-turn-server), but didn't get answer for my query

I'm expecting below kind of response:

- Full Cone - Full Cone : STUN
- Symmetric - Port Restricted : TURN

Comment: Assuming it's correct, the linked SO Q/A goes beyond what you're asking. It tells that it depends on both sides, not on a single side.